# bundle install not installing all dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am on Mac OS X, and when I run sudo bundle install, it installs several gems on the target machine:

```
Installing ptools (1.2.1) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.5) 
Using rails (3.0.5) 
Installing rails_config (0.2.4) 
Using shoulda (2.11.3) 
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ rails console
Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install rake-0.9.2
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake-0.9.2' (>= 0) in any repository
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install rake -v=0.9.2
Successfully installed rake-0.9.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-0.9.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-0.9.2...
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install rake-0.9.2
^CERROR:  Interrupted
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ rails console
Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sduo gem install i18n -v=0.6.0
-bash: sduo: command not found
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install i18n -v=0.6.0
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.6.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for i18n-0.6.0...
```

So, it should be safe to assume that dependencies are resolved for the app, and things are ready to go. But they are not.

When I run rails console, I constantly receive output about more and more and more and more unresolved dependencies:

```
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ rails console
Could not find tzinfo-0.3.29 in any of the sources
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install tzingo -v=0.3.29
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'tzingo' (= 0.3.29) in any repository
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install tzinfo -v=0.3.29
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.29
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-0.3.29...
Installing RDoc documentation for tzinfo-0.3.29...
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ rails console
Could not find polyglot-0.3.2 in any of the sources
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install polyglot -v=0.3.2
Successfully installed polyglot-0.3.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for polyglot-0.3.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for polyglot-0.3.2...
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ rails console
Could not find treetop-1.4.10 in any of the sources
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install treetop -v=1.4.10
Successfully installed treetop-1.4.10
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for treetop-1.4.10...
Installing RDoc documentation for treetop-1.4.10...
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ rails console
Could not find mail-2.2.19 in any of the sources
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ sudo gem install mail -v=2.2.19
Successfully installed mail-2.2.19
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mail-2.2.19...
Installing RDoc documentation for mail-2.2.19...
imac-cf:gnymbus apple$ rails console
Could not find addressable-2.2.6 in any of the sources
```

Is Rails really this difficult? Do I really have to install dependencies manually, one by one? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was that I had to not run bundle install using sudo.

What a pain. Why are these sorts of things not documented somewhere?

Comment: It [is documented somewhere](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html) (using a pretty standard form of documentation on a Unix-based system, I might add); the manpage explicitly states that you shouldn't use `sudo` while issuing a `bundle install`.

Answer (score 6):

1. Delete *Gemfile.lock*
2. Delete all gems under root (it's prefer)
3. Update rubygems
4. `gem install bundler`
5. `bundle install`

Answer (score 6):

I used

```
bundle update
```

it updated all the Gemfiles and installed the missing gems. No sudo, since using RVM

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Vagrant`, try restarting your `VM`. Often when going back and forth between work and home I've noticed that the `VM`'s connection to the outside world gets hosed. In this case running `rails console` will check for any unmet dependencies and fail simply because it can't connect to ruby `gems.org`.

It's a really bad error message and has caught me off-guard on more than one occasion.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OSX, I had the same problem. All I needed to do was:

```
gem install bundler
```