# Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources

Tags: rubygems, passenger, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded from Rails 3.0.3 to 3.2.1. The upgrade went smoothly on my Mac but I'm having trouble getting a 3.2.1 instance of my app running on my Ubuntu production server. The error I'm getting is this:

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Obviously, other people have had this same problem before. Unfortunately, [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060069/bundle-install-not-installing-all-dependencies) doesn't fix it for me. Doing `sudo bundle install` doesn't seem to make a difference.

I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367880/rake-aborted-cannot-load-such-file-bundler-setup) but I don't understand what exactly the OP did that fixed the problem.

There's [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676890/passenger-says-bundlergemnotfound-error-while-the-bundle-install-says-its-ther) as well but the OP's problem there just kind of went away by itself.

And I do have the `i18n` gem installed:

```
$ gem list | grep i18n
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
```

I have no idea what could be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run `bundle list | grep i18n` and output that please?

Comment: what is the command that you are trying to run that gives you the error?

Comment: I just get it when I try to load my app in the browser.

Comment: Just to clarify, the link in your post suggests NOT using "sudo bundle install"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly the same error. Are you using rvm and passenger?

If you had rvm installed before starting passenger installation, after passenger finishes its installation it gives you the instructions for updating apache configuration with something similar to:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/ruby
```

I've installed passenger with global gemset but later I created another gemset which I used for my app (let's call this new gemset 'foo').

The solution that worked for me was to change 'global' to 'foo' in the 3rd line:

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p125@foo/ruby
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @draganstankovic, but it's not really a solution. The whole point of the global gemset is so it can be shared by many applications.

Comment: @dangerousdave Please, read again my answer. The point is on syncing passenger with whatever gemset he uses. (be it global, foo or bar, it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 5):

`bundle install --deployment`
worked for me.

Comment: Running a bundle install fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

An .rvmrc file at the root of your app solves this problem. Via [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/):

```
# my-app-name/.rvmrc
if [[ -s "/Users/sutto/.rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@my-app-name" ]] ; then
  . "/Users/sutto/.rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@my-app-name"
else
  rvm --create use  "ree-1.8.7-2010.02@my-app-name"
fi
```

Replace with the correct user, Ruby version and gemset where applicable. (Linux users will probably have home/username/.rvm...)

Now let's add the setup_load_paths.rb so passenger has the correct paths (shouldn't have anything to change here):

```
# my-app-name/config/setup_load_paths.rb
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    raise "RVM gem is currently unavailable."
  end
end

# If you're not using Bundler at all, remove lines bellow
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I realised I was using jRuby to rake (I was using RVM). With Ruby it went without a problem :)

Therefore, make sure you're using Ruby instead of jRuby. Just in case you're using RVM as well, use:

```
rvm list
```

To get the list of all rubies installed and

```
rvm use ruby-...
```

To select it.

Comment: This worked for me, and makes more sense than renaming global to foo